# parsing quotes in json

Tags: python, json

I had a problem parsing quotes in json. I use python 2.7.
my json file is here.

```
{
    "table": "test",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "comment_id" : "11111",
            "title" : "Worked great with limited space",
            "comment" : "We have a very "small" kitchen but wanted a stylish refrigerator that was counter depth. This model made great use of the limited space. The deep door shelves are great and the touch controls on the door make it easy."
        },
        {
            "comment_id" : "22222",
            "title" : "Amazing Refrigerator",
            "comment" : "Customer Service was "FANTASTIC" when I was shopping for this refrigerator. This refrigerator fit perfectly in our space, it only took 2 hours to cool from delivery. Has a ton of space and the lighting is great in it"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my source is here:

```
def create_file(from_file, to_file):
    with open(from_file, "r") as f:
        result = f.read().replace('\\', '').replace('&amp;', '&').replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&lt;', '<')
        res = json.loads(result, strict=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")

    f = open(to_file, "w")
    f.write("id" + '\t' + "title" + '\t' + "review" + '\n') # write a first line.
    pattern = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.;:,!?&]")

    for data in res['rows']:
        output = "\""
        output += str(data['comment_id'] + '"\t"')
        output += str(pattern.sub(' ', data['title']) + '"\t"')
        output += str(pattern.sub(' ', data['comment']) + '""\n')
        f.write(output)
    f.close()
```

the error code is here:

```
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 20119 column 154 (char 1495987)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

if the quotes("") are included in comment fields in json.
the error occurs, how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your JSON file valid? I don't see embedded double quotes being escaped.

Comment: Try http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json ...

Comment: Could be that this particular piece is ruining it: `.replace('\\', '')`. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: as you can see, my source code is included .replace('\\', ''). but it has an error. I need to parsing the json file, but quotes in json file make delimiter error. I can't modify json file so I need to change my python source code.

Comment: The file you show us isn't json.... Those quotes need to be escaped. You read the file and then remove escape characters so that even if the original file was correctly escaped, it isn't any more. Get rid of the replace. Are those other replaces there because of html entities?

Comment: I'd say, first parse the JSON, then do the replacing for HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

your json is not valid, it should be something like this, :-)
use a valid json

```
{
    "table": "test",
    "rows": [{
        "comment_id": "11111",
        "title": "Worked great with limited space",
        "comment": "We have a very \"small\" kitchen but wanted a stylish refrigerator that was counter depth. This model made great use of the limited space. The deep door shelves are great and the touch controls on the door make it easy."
    }, {
        "comment_id": "22222",
        "title": "Amazing Refrigerator",
        "comment": "Customer Service was \"FANTASTIC\" when I was shopping for this refrigerator. This refrigerator fit perfectly in our space, it only took 2 hours to cool from delivery. Has a ton of space and the lighting is great in it"
    }]
}
```